# Fabric: Inserting the hostname into a config file

Tags: fabric

I have a Fabric script I'm in the process of creating, and I want it to change the following line in a config file:

```
Hostname=localhost
```

I want it to include the actual host name, for example:

```
Hostname=mypc
```

I tried to do so with the following line:

```python
fabric.contrib.files.sed(
        '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf',
        before='Hostname=localhost',
        after='Hostname='"$HOSTNAME",
        use_sudo=True, backup='')
```

But unfortunately, it won't work, and I've tried various combinations of quotes and double quotes. It will literally put "Hostname=$HOSTNAME" into the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work like that. The sed stuff is all inside single quotes. Just bind a name to the hostname value, and use Python interpolation to send it to the `sed` function. You might even be able to use the `env.host` setting. But an example of using this would look like this:

```python
hostname = run("hostname -f")
fabric.contrib.files.sed(
        '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf',
        before='Hostname=localhost',
        after='Hostname=%s' % hostname,
        use_sudo=True, backup='')
```